# Can't to add namespace field to roleRef in RoleBinding

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I want to add role from namespace `kube-system` in my `MyRoleBinding.yaml` file like that:

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata: 
  name: myrolebinding
  namespace: default
subjects: 
- kind: ServiceAccount 
  name: myservice
  namespace: default
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef: 
  kind: Role
  name: system:controller:token-cleaner
  namespace: kube-system
  apiGroup: ""
```

But when I run `kubectl apply -f MyRoleBinding.yaml` I get:

> error: error validating "MyRoleBinding.yaml": error validating data:
>   ValidationError(RoleBinding.roleRef): **unknown** field "namespace" in
>   io.k8s.api.rbac.v1.RoleRef; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn
>   validation off with --validate=false

I am running in the `default` namespace, is it because of this ?
I tried to run:
`kubectl apply -f MyRoleBinding.yaml --namespace=kube-system` but I am getting the same error.

I also tried to add an existing role in the `defaul` namespace by using:

```
roleRef: 
  kind: Role
  name: read-pods
  namespace: default
  apiGroup: ""
```

and I got the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `roleRef` field doesn't support namespace. You can use `roleRef` either with ClusterRoles which are not namespaced or with Roles which always has to be in the same namespace as the RoleBinding. See also the [reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#roleref-v1-rbac-authorization-k8s-io).

Comment: Old reference version not deployed anymore, new one is 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.22/#roleref-v1-rbac-authorization-k8s-io

Answer (score 0):

RoleRef doesn't support namespace clause, excerpt from [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/d6967f358e9f35ea69657925d5da7f91df653bab/staging/src/k8s.io/api/rbac/v1/types.go):

```
// RoleRef contains information that points to the role being used
type RoleRef struct {
    // APIGroup is the group for the resource being referenced
    APIGroup string `json:"apiGroup" protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=apiGroup"`
    // Kind is the type of resource being referenced
    Kind string `json:"kind" protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=kind"`
    // Name is the name of resource being referenced
    Name string `json:"name" protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=name"`
}
```